# Random generator Letters and Integers

Tags: java

SAS pgmr Learning Java for android random generator-'Rank Amateur'. Suppose I wish to display random of A/B/C/D. I suppose I would do a random of 1/2/3/4 and then 'if 2 then display B, if 4 then display D'?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the letters in an array. Then get a random one like so from the array.

```
int dex = new Random().nextInt(letters.length);
String random = (letters[dex]);
```

But it basically comes out the same.